# Auto complete orders when a renewal successful payment is made on a subscription in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin for subscriptions and it is recurring the order on subscription renewal and what I need is that when the order recurring order is created after successful subscription renewal payment the order status should changed to completed.

I have tried to use unsuccessfully the following hooks:

- `woocommerce_renewal_order_payment_complete`
- `woocommerce_order_status_changed`
- `woocommerce_payment_complete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WooCommerce Subscriptions you need to use `woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete` action hook, that is triggered when a renewal payment is made on a subscription.

You can try the following that will update the current order status to completed:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'subscription_payment_complete_hook_callback', 10, 1);
function subscription_payment_complete_hook_callback( $subscription ) {
    // Get the current order
    $current_order = $subscription->get_last_order( 'all', 'any' );

    // For Paypal recurring orders
    if( $current_order->get_payment_method() === 'paypal' ) {

        // Update status to completed
        $current_order->update_status('completed');
    }
}
```

Related documentation: [WooCommerce Subscriptions action hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#section-1)

Comment: is this hook called every time as well as new order is created or renewal of subscription?

Answer (score 3):

I believe for renewals the hook that should be used is: woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete

This also accepts the $subscription parameter

Comment: As seen here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, as [WooCommerce Subscription API](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/) has changed, this seems to work:

```
/*Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}

/*Auto Complete all WooCommerce Renewal Subscription orders.*/
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete', 'subscription_renewal_payment_complete_callback', 10, 2);
function subscription_renewal_payment_complete_callback( $subscription, $order ) {
    $order->update_status('completed');
}
```